# timezones in notification application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, momentjs

I write a notification based web app. I have to set notification times in the client side, send to the server, save to mysql database, continuously check for notifications, when the time is ready, send alert to the client. Simple as pie. Problem is, i'm pretty noob with timezones stuff. My server is in GMT-4, I am currently GMT+2, but in a few month i'll be in GMT +1 because of winter time. I can't get my head around the solution.
So far, i use moment.js on the server side and javascript built in Date object on the client side and i save times in unix timestamp.

My question in short: How to keep track on timezones and stuff, if i don't want any problem if i move my server from gmt-4 to lets say gmt-5 and don't want any problem with seasonal timesone change.

Thanks to spend time on my problem!
Best regards.

Comment: You can go with utc right?

Comment: I assume a could... Do you think that's the best solution for this problem?

Comment: ya . And Its happening in our live project also

Comment: Thank You! If You write a proper answer for this, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of storing timestamps is simple: Store them in UTC.

As for displaying them in client again, Take the device (client) timezone and convert utc to  device time zone.